# Binding errors in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way I can see the binding errors in while developing Xamarin Forms apps? The Application Output tab shows nothing but the binding doesn't work. How can I debug bindings?

Comment: what kind of binding errors are you having a hard time figuring out?

Comment: Have you tried to set a BreakPoint on the attribute you want to bind?

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest you to add `EmptyConverter`:

```
public class EmptyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then create instance of converter on your page:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:EmptyConverter x:Key="EmptyConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then add converter to label:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource EmptyConverter}}"/>
```

Put breakpoints in `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods and you'll be able to see all changes of binded values.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Compiled Bindings:
https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings

You will have gain performance and precise error reporting