# XAML Binding to label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I have a page for displaying database items.

```
public ListItemsPage()
{
    DatabaseHelper tmpDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
    InitializeComponent();

    listView.ItemsSource = tmpDBHelper.GetItems();
}
```

These items have 4 columns: Id as `Guid`, MandantId as `Guid`, UpdateAt as `DateTime` and Url as `String`.

Now I'd like to bind them in my XAML like this.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Portable.Pages.ListItemsPage"
             Title="DbItemExample">
  <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout Padding="20,0,20,0"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

              <Label Text="{Binding Id}"
                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
              <Label Text="{Binding Url}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
              <Label Text="{Binding MandantId}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
              <Label Text="{Binding UpdateAt}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

If this helps, here is my model of which the db table was generated.

```
class DbItem
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid MandantId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateAt { get; set; }
}
```

It's only displaying the Url and UpdateAt. Why is that?

Comment: Are `Url` and `MandantId` comes from database?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Yes they do. I get the items in the cs file with all the properties.

Comment: I would add `EmptyConverter` and would see if binding works.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy It does have the values expected in it. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.

Like suggested from Egor Gromadskiy I implemented an EmptyConverter ([Binding errors in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315567/binding-errors-in-xamarin-forms)). It seems like Xamarin can't convert a Guid to a string automatically.

Simply changing the `value` to `value.ToString()` in method `Convert()` did it.

Comment: _It's only displaying the Id_ - but `Id` is `Guid`, too. So why `Id` is showed?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Sorry typo, it's displaying the Url and UpdateAt. Still strange it's calling the ToString() on DateTime but not on Guid.